# Optionally safety-checked cast on possibly incomplete type

Tags: c++, incomplete-type, template-instantiation

Pursuant to a simple, intrusively reference-counted object system, I have a `template<typename T> class Handle`, which is meant to be instantiated with a subclass of `CountedBase`. `Handle<T>` holds a pointer to a `T`, and its destructor calls `DecRef` (defined in `CountedBase`) on that pointer.

Normally, this would cause problems when trying to limit header dependencies by using forward declarations:

```
#include "Handle.h"

class Foo; // forward declaration

struct MyStruct {
    Handle<Foo> foo; // This is okay, but...
};

void Bar() {
    MyStruct ms;
}   // ...there's an error here, as the implicit ~MyStruct calls
    // Handle<Foo>::~Handle(), which wants Foo to be a complete
    // type so it can call Foo::DecRef(). To solve this, I have
    // to #include the definition of Foo.
```

As a solution, I rewrote `Handle<T>::~Handle()` as follows:

```
template<typename T>
Handle<T>::~Handle() {
    reinterpret_cast<CountedBase*>(m_ptr)->DecRef();
}
```

Note that I'm using `reinterpret_cast` here instead of `static_cast`, since `reinterpret_cast` doesn't require the definition of `T` to be complete. Of course, it also won't perform pointer adjustment for me... but as long as I'm careful with layouts (`T` must have `CountedBase` as its leftmost ancestor, must not inherit from it virtually, and on a couple of unusual platforms, some extra vtable magic is necessary), it's safe.

What would be *really* nice, though, would be if I could get that extra layer of `static_cast` safety where possible. In practice, the definition of `T` is *usually* complete at the point where `Handle::~Handle` is instantiated, making it a perfect moment to double-check that `T` actually inherits from `CountedBase`. If it's incomplete, there's not much I can do... but if it's complete, a sanity check would be good.

Which brings us, finally, to my question: 
**Is there any way to do a compile-time check that `T` inherits from `CountedBase` which will not cause a (spurious) error when `T` is not complete?**

[Usual disclaimer: I'm aware that there are potentially unsafe and/or UB aspects to the use of incomplete types in this way. Nevertheless, after a great deal of cross-platform testing and profiling, I've determined that this is the most practical approach given certain unique aspects of my use case. I'm interested in the compile-time checking question, not a general code review.]

Comment: So you want to apply the compile time check only if `T` is complete?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't do a `is_complete` traits (which is not UB) as this [one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56bb09c812f521c6)

Comment: @m.s. Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using SFINAE on `sizeof` to check whether the type is complete :

```
struct CountedBase {
    void decRef() {}
};

struct Incomplete;
struct Complete : CountedBase {};

template <std::size_t> struct size_tag;

template <class T>
void decRef(T *ptr, size_tag<sizeof(T)>*) {
    std::cout << "static\n";
    static_cast<CountedBase*>(ptr)->decRef();
}

template <class T>
void decRef(T *ptr, ...) {
    std::cout << "reinterpret\n";
    reinterpret_cast<CountedBase*>(ptr)->decRef();
}

template <class T>
struct Handle {
    ~Handle() {
        decRef(m_ptr, nullptr);
    }

    T *m_ptr = nullptr;
};

int main() {
    Handle<Incomplete> h1;
    Handle<Complete> h2;
}
```

Output (note that the order of destruction is reversed) :

```
static
reinterpret
```

[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbb89eeec1767389)

Trying it with a complete type that does not derive from `CountedBase` yields :

```
main.cpp:16:5: error: static_cast from 'Oops *' to 'CountedBase *' is not allowed
```

That being said, I think a more elegant (and more explicit) approach would be to introduce a class template `incomplete<T>`, such that `Handle<incomplete<Foo>>` compiles to the `reinterpret_cast`, and anything else tries to `static_cast`.

Comment: I think it is UB as `~Handle()` will break ODR when sometime `T` is complete and sometime not.

Comment: @Jarod42 I understand what you mean, but I have no idea. But wouldn't that be the case of any implementation of OP's requirements ?

Comment: I think so as I stated in comment of the question.